# Return statement is not working inside if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript

Return statement is not working inside if condition in javascript. After 
alert it is going to next page instead of staying in current page.

Code:

```
function checkAddressField() {
  var textArea = document.getElementById("address");
  var arrayOfLines = textArea.value.split("\n");
  for(var i = 0;i < arrayOfLines.length;i++){
    arrayOfLines[i];
  }

  if (arrayOfLines[1] == "") {
    alert("Minimum 2 lines need to enter in address");
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: You return nothing..There is no code saying to go to another page. Some code are missing in your question

Comment: @Weedoze I believe he is coming from a `<form onsubmit="return checkAddressField();">`. At least I hope so.

Comment: assuming this happens when the user clicks a link, you need to prevent the default action of the anchor element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Who is calling `checkAddressField`? Why do you think the `return` statement is not working? What do you expect it to do that it is not? Are you sure that you do not want to check for `arrayOfLines.length`? Why do you an expressions that does nothing in the body of your `for` statement?

Comment: @syazdani — They might be, but that's speculation at this stage. They should provide a [mcve] before the question can really be answered.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to `return false;` instead of just `return;`ing.